# Не получается получить данные с инпутов через форму с методом POST

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
`html`
<form action="vendor/signUp.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class ="modal3 modal-display-none">
    <div class="reg-modal-wind">
        <div class="modal-window-containing3">
            <div class="modal-header3">
                <h3 class="modal-header-title3">Регистрация</h3>
                <button class="escape3" type="button">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body3">
                <div class="input-reg">
                        <span class="plsINP span-input-login">Придумайте Логин:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="login" class="inp_aut imagine-log" placeholder="Логин">
                </div>
                <div class="input-reg-mail-reg">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-login">Адрес электронной почты:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="inp_aut mail-reg" placeholder="Электронная почта">
                </div>
                <div class="input-inmagine-pswd">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-password">Придумайье пароль:</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="inp_aut pswd-reg" vlaue="" placeholder="Пароль">
                </div> 
                <div class="input-confirm-pswd">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-password">Подтвердите пароль:</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" class="inp_aut pswd-reg-conf" vlaue="" placeholder="Повторите Пароль">
                </div> 
                <div  onclick="location.href='vendor/signUp.php';" class="button_reg-block">
                    <a href="vendor/signUp.php" class="button_reg">
                    Зарегестрироваться</a>
                </div>
                <div class="if-log-block">
                    <span>Уже есть учетная запись,тогда войди!</span>
                    <a href="#" class="log-cho">Войти</a>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer3">
                <div class="modal-footer-links">
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/VK-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/INST-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/FACEBOOK-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
`php`
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);
    if($password === $password_confirm){
        if($password>=0)
        $_SESSION['message']= "Пароль слишком короткий!(Минимальное значение-6)";
        elseif($password>=6)
        $_SESSION['message']= "Отлично!";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message']= "Пароли не совпадают";
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }
    if(empty($login)) {
        echo 'error';
        }
        else echo $login;
    if(empty($email)) {
        echo 'error';
        }
        else echo $email;
    if(empty($password)) {
        echo 'error';
        }
        else echo $password;
    if(empty($password_confirm)) {
        echo 'error';`введите сюда код`
        }
        else echo $password_confirm;
?>
<p>Перейти на глайвнуй страницу <a href="../index.php">Здесь</a></p>
```

Comment: Как это не получается получить данные с формы? Ошибка? Или они просто не приходят?

Comment: Ошибок нет.Просто не приходят данные.($login,$email,$password ,$password_confirm -пустые).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, не знаю что за способ такой отправки данных. Но просто замените эту часто кода:

```
<div  onclick="location.href='vendor/signUp.php';" class="button_reg-block">
      <a href="vendor/signUp.php" class="button_reg">
         Зарегестрироваться</a>
</div>
```

На это:

```
<div class="button_reg-block">
          <button type="submit">sign up</button>
    </div>
```

У вас данные не приходят, потому что у вас не правильном оформлена форма.

Comment: Большое спасибо за уделенное моему вопросу внимание и корректный ответ:все получилось.Могу объяснить в чем заключалась моя ошибка.Дело в том,что при верстке макета,я был слабо дальновиден и сделал в форме вместо кнопок- дивы, с ссылками,позже при написании движка на php, с помощью js указал ссылку на страницу  для отправки и проверки формы для регистрации.Из-за этого sql запрос не проходил и данные с инпутов не обновлялись.